# Event only working the first time

Tags: lua, coronasdk, luabind, corona-storyboard

I have this image:

```
local core = display.newImage("images/core.png", (display.contentWidth/2), display.contentHeight/5)
```

And when something happened i do this:

```
spinCore()
```

Calling this function:

```
local function spinCore()
    transition.to(core,{time=500,rotation=360})
end
```

This is working, but only the first time i do this, by the next ones it isn´t working. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: can you provide further codes it's really  hard to point the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do like:

```
local function spinCore()
    transition.to(core,{time=500,rotation=core.rotation+360})
end
```

Keep coding.................. :)